# Getting stack traces while developing a Firefox extension

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon

I'm working on a rather huge Firefox extension that uses a lot of HTML and jQuery loaded into a XUL window. Is there some way of augmenting the error console in Firefox to show full stack traces instead of just the file and line where something went wrong?

Comment: That's actually three unrelated questions, maybe create separate questions for the other two and edit this question to remove them? At least one of your questions isn't answerable without additional information (callbacks - you need to provide an example). Also, you've set the firefox-addon-sdk tag but your question doesn't sound like you are using the Add-on SDK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, unfortunately the Error Console won't show stacks. You can use the following work-around:

```
try
{
  ...
}
catch (e)
{
  // Code has thrown an exception, add stack information to it
  e = String(e) + "\n\n" + new Error().stack;
  throw e;
}
```

You most likely want to use this code only when debugging - it's a pretty ugly approach to use in production and you cannot avoid losing information about the exception.